# Trouble with conducting a simple transaction via Vanilla JS

Tags: web3.js, transfer, jsonrpc-api, sol

My code used to work in early-mid November. It used to be a simple SOL transaction from wallet to another through a click of a button and then it just stopped working as I was dealing with something called “buffer”. It’s been really annoying and very hard to find a solution to this even though I’ve been looking for ages. Apparently, the reason why this is happening is because the bundle given by the Solana documentation itself does not contain all of the dependencies which is a big issue.

I'm sticking to Vanilla JS to keep everything simplified, I don't want to use React or a framework of some sort. The bundle I was initially using is currently bugging out with an interesting error..

```
POST https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/ 403

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code": 403, "message":"Access forbidden, contact your app developer or support@rpcpool.com."}
```

Here's the bundle I was initially using (used to work): https://unpkg.com/@solana/web3.js@v1.33.0/lib/index.iife.js

It used to work, finding a solution to this has been really difficult. I don't know where to start as I can't find any answers anywhere. I'd really appreciate it if someone could possibly help me out in this case.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the public RPC at `https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com`, there are very strict rate limits as outlined [here](https://docs.solana.com/cluster/rpc-endpoints#mainnet-beta).

Getting 403 means that you were banned for some abuse. Recommend getting another free RPC elsewhere. You can find a list of RPCs [here](https://solana.com/rpc).

Comment: Ah. Why would I be banned? I've been doing my testing on mainnet-beta for some time now, is that why? How can I revert this and where can I find an alternative?

Comment: You probably hit some rate limit from usage on your site. I gave a link to a list of alternatives in the answer.

Comment: Yes but is it possible for this ban to be permanent? It's been a couple of weeks since my website stopped working.

Comment: Yes, it is permanent

Comment: What if the site was reuploaded under another domain? Would that fix the issue?

Comment: Possibly. That is trying to get around a ban though

Comment: Just checked and it's still bugging out, I think it's the bundle I'm using. I just want an updated version that works 100% fine just like it did in November. I'm not sure why it stopped working.. SOLANA is so complicated.

Answer (score -1):

Is there a problem with the compiler? Buffering went out the door twenty-years ago.. TLP (Studying) Something could be squeezing your bandwidth; has someone joined your download line that you are not aware of? Maybe, you've become a Hot Hub, sort of. / I am no familiar with transaction code, but the hardware check is often overlooked. /
Happy Holidays TLP 5:25 PM 13-Dec 2022 (My email account is not secure: Ted3611@outlook.com so it's best not to reply at this time.) Just food for thought.

Comment: What does this mean? How could this even be possible. Who has control over stuff like this and I'm not sure why I'd be targeted. Would appreciate it if someone could help me find a solution ASAP. It's definitely the bundle I'm using, and it doesn't even begin there.. I can't even fetch the address' balance via the public SOLANA API..